# Advanced NSPredicate statement in Core Data (string comparison)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate

I'm now trying to filter the items using the following approach:

My managed object is like that:

```
@interface MyManagedObject:NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

@end
```

For example, the name of an object is "ABCDEF GHIJKL company"

When I search with the string "BCD IJK pan" or "BCD pan", etc,

(BCD is a substring of ABCDEF, IJK is a substring of GHIJKL, and pan is a substring of company)

it should be able to find the object.

I have no idea how to write a predicate with this. I tried to use predicateWithBlock: but Core Data doesn't support the predicate from predicateWithBlock:

I also tried to fetch all objects first and filter the results with predicate block. But it's extremely slow because I have around 10M objects in the Core Data.

So I would like to ask can I do this in one predicate statement? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `LIKE` if you include the wildcard character `*`.  So if you search with `self LIKE %@, @"*BCD*IJK*pan*` it will find it